# How to manually register/unregister a Key Storage Provider on Windows 10/11

Tags: cryptography, certificate, smartcard

How do I manually register/unregister a Key Storage Provider on Windows 10/11 and what is the problem?

Using Microsoft’s Event Viewer, in Administrative Events, I get the record of Level “Error” that says “The "***" provider was not loaded because initialization failed.”, ErrorCode “The requested operation is not supported. 0x80090029 (-2146893783 NTE_NOT_SUPPORTED)” and Source “Microsoft-Windows-CertificateServicesClient-CertEnroll”.

I tried removing the KSP from the Registry entry, which also contained other KSPs "`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Cryptography\Configuration\Local\Default\00010001\KEY_STORAGE`" and then I deleted the KSP's Registry entry for the DLL, "`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Cryptography\Providers\***`".

The KSP still remained registered and faulting, which causes the Certificate Propagation Service and the SmartCard Service to stop working.